# â”‚ lines of my terminal are garbled on the Web, why?

Tags: web, amazon-s3, terminal

When I `fwupdmgr get-devices --show-all-devices > /tmp/all-devices.txt` and upload the result to S3 https://s.natalian.org/2020-09-12/all-devices.txt

The rendering in my simple terminal:

[image: Terminal]

Looks different to that of my browser:

[image: Browser]

How can I make the text on the Web look like my terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an encoding issue, you need to explicitly set character encoding on the object so that when it's served the browser knows how to interpret these characters.

If you want to apply the encoding to an existing object via Web Console, you can do so by selecting the object on S3, going to the Properties tab -> Metadata and setting it to something likke `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

[image: screenshot of S3 dasbhoard]

You can also set this during upload both AWS CLI and the various SDKs have parameters that allow to set metadata and/or content-type on the put operation.

Example with AWS CLI:

```sh
aws s3 cp origin/my_file.txt s3://your_bucket/ --content-type="text/plain;charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just upload with the aws cli like so https://github.com/kaihendry/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/upload#L82 ... so do I need to override the CLI for text files??

Comment: Yes, you can do `aws s3 cp origin/my_file.txt s3://my_bucket/my_file.txt --content-type="text/plain;charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: find it bizaare that i need to jump an extra hoop for text files, why doesn't the https://github.com/aws/aws-cli do it?

Comment: Probably a question to be asked to the author of the tool. It could have to do with the original encoding of the file, the default locale of the host system or simply because the file contains non-ascii characters. Your original question was answered though.